# Atualizar página com botão, mas sem piscar

Tags: javascript, ajax

Eu queria que ao clicar no botão `atualizar` a página atualizasse automaticamente mas sem piscar, sem o refresh

```css
.transferencias {
width: 59%;
float: left;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-top: 25px;
}

.transferencias div.desktop {
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
height: auto;
}

.transferencias div.desktop p.titulo {
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;
color: black;
line-height: 2;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.transferencias div.desktop span.botao_atualizar {
    float: right;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Rajdhani', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 8px 6px 0px 0px;
cursor: default;
text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="transferencias">
<div class="desktop">
<p class="titulo">LIVE </span>
<span class="botao_atualizar"> atualizar </span> </span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Só com HTML e CSS (até onde sei) não é possível, vai precisar usar também JavaScript com a técnica/tecnologia AJAX.

Você tem várias opções para isso, dentre elas:

- Nativas: [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHTTPRequest) (XML HTTP Request) e [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (sem suporte ao Internet Explorer).
- Bibliotecas (dentre outras): [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) e [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Qual escolher depende do seu objetivo e de como está o seu projeto.

- O **XHR** vai funcionar em todos os casos, porém é mais verboso.
- A **Fetch API** é mais simples, porém ainda não apresenta suporte
  amplo.
- A solução do **jQuery** é útil caso já esteja usando jQuery em alguma
  parte de seu projeto, pois do contrário é um peso em termos de
  performance.
- Com o **Axios** basta adicionar a library ao seu HTML para usar, a
  sintaxe é tão simples quanto a do Fetch API e apenas abstrai o XHR, o
  que significa que seu suporte é tão amplo quanto.

## Exemplo usando XHR

Um exemplo bem simples abaixo.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "URL_PARA_BUSCAR_RESULTADOS";
xhr.open("GET", url);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            var res = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
            /// usa os dados em 'res'
        } else {
            alert('Erro...')
        }
    }
};

xhr.send();
```

Eu tenho um CodePen mostrando em funcionamento: https://codepen.io/aanizio/pen/gZxPQe